# JRuby multi-core processing usages

Tags: ruby, multithreading, asynchronous, multiprocessing, jruby

Is it possible to run code blocks on multiple cores? For an example for loops and alike? If its possible without much overhead why not use it all the time? Can I somehow pass variables across multiple cores?

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to execute code/blocks on multiple cores but its not that simple e.g. the backing structure has to be ready for this (none of the core structures such as `Array`, `Hash` are thread-safe).

you can't simply `(1..100).each { |i| puts i }` run multi-threaded without a different (unpredictable) outcome than in a single threaded case.

in case or variables you need to synchronize access or use thread-safe structures if they're meant to be shared between threads.

maybe in your case I would not start on a green field, these concepts and some of the back practices for concurrent programming are available using the [concurrent-ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) gem.

for running blocks in parallel learn about [executors/thread-pools](http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/file.thread_pools.html)

there's also [thread-safe structures](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby#thread-safe-value-objects-structures-and-collections) if you're interested in "safe"-ly sharing variables between threads (CR tried to introduce a memory model as Ruby lacks an official one - JRuby has some guaranteed e.g. class-variables being volatile - changes visible across threads)